# D2D coordinates not matching screen coordinates

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct2d

I am using D2D with D3D11. I have some code that uses GetCursorpos() from the windows API which is then converted to client coordinates and then draws a small circle at this position using D2D FillEllipse(). The screen to client coordinates work perfectly but for some reason D2D draws the circle a small distance from the expected location (tens of pixels) as if the coordinate had been scaled by a small factor so that the error gets larger as the circle is drawn further from (0, 0). 
I noticed changing the dpi for the D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES affects this 'scaling' so I suspect the problem has something to do with dpi. This is the code for creating the D2D render target from the DXGI surface I obtained from the swapchain in my D3D11 code.

```
    // Create render target
    float dpiX, dpiY;
    this->factory->GetDesktopDpi(&dpiX, &dpiY);
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtDesc = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED),
        dpiX,
        dpiY
    );
    AssertHResult(this->factory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(
        surface.Get(),
        &rtDesc,
        &this->renderTarget
    ), "Failed to create D2D render target");
```

Here, dpiX and dpiY become 96 which I notice is also the constant that GetDpiForWindow() from the windows API returns when it is not dpi aware.

I want to know how I can fix my code so that it will draw the circle at the position given by GetCursorPos().

More relevant code:

**Driver code**

```
    Vector3f cursPos = input.GetCursorPos();
    DrawCircle(Colour::Green, cursPos.x, cursPos.y, 3/*radius*/);
```

**Input**

```
    POINT pt{};
    ::GetCursorPos(&pt);
    // Convert from screen pixels to client pixels
    return ConvertPixelSpace(this->hWnd, (float)pt.x, (float)pt.x, PixelSpace::Screen, PixelSpace::Client);
```

**Direct2D**

```
void DrawCircle(const Colour& c, float centreX, float centreY, float radius, PixelSpace ps)
{
    Vector3f centre = ConvertPixelSpace(this->gfx.hWnd, centreX, centreY, ps, PixelSpace::Client);
    centreX = centre.x;
    centreY = centre.y;
    D2D1_ELLIPSE el{};
    el.point.x = centreX;
    el.point.y = centreY;
    el.radiusX = radius;
    el.radiusY = radius;
    auto brush = this->CreateBrush(c);
    this->renderTarget->FillEllipse(
        &el,
        brush.Get()
    );
}
```

**PixelSpace Conversion**

```
Vector3f ConvertPixelSpace(HWND hWnd, float x, float y, PixelSpace curSpace, PixelSpace newSpace)
{
    RECT rc = GetClientRectOfWindow(hWnd);
    struct
    {
        float top, left, width, height;
    } rectf;
    rectf.top = static_cast<float>(rc.top);
    rectf.left = static_cast<float>(rc.left);
    rectf.width = static_cast<float>(rc.right - rc.left);
    rectf.height = static_cast<float>(rc.bottom - rc.top);

    // Convert to client space
    if (curSpace == PixelSpace::Screen)
    {
        x -= rectf.left;
        y -= rectf.top;
    }

    // Convert to new space
    if (newSpace == PixelSpace::Screen)
    {
        x += rectf.left;
        y += rectf.top;
    }

    return Vector3f(x, y);
}

RECT GetClientRectOfWindow(HWND hWnd)
{
    RECT rc;
    ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    // Pretty sure these are valid casts.
    // rc.top is stored directly after rc.left and this forms a POINT struct
    ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.left));
    ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.right));
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: There's probably a bug in your code, but you don't show the relevant code, or a reproducing sample.

Comment: @Simon Mourier Thanks for the reply, I've added more relevant code

Comment: Few hints: 1) you can pass 0 for dpi in D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES, 2) when you see float coords with D2D, it means it's talking DIPS not pixels, unless you used the ID2D1DeviceContext::SetUnitMode method before, 3) D2D is in general talking in screen coords, not client (what's a client for it?), unless you used transform, effects, etc.. From what I understand, your FillEllipse seems to use client coords, should be "screen", but it depends how you created and setup the render target... Or give us a complete small reproducing sample.

Comment: @Simon Mourier Turns out I was creating the d3d11 device and swapchain with the window's dimensions instead of the client area and this caused the 'scaling'. Thanks so much because if it weren't for you I wouldn't have created the reproducing sample which lead me to find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was creating the D3D11 swapchain with the window area instead of the client area.

```
    RECT rect{};
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect); // !!! This should be GetClientRect()
    this->width = rect.right - rect.left;
    this->height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scDesc{};
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    //...
```